# Can I become a Commercial Pilot if I had OCD?

Tags: faa-regulations, medical

In a few weeks, I am going to get off my medication for OCD treatment. The FAA says if episodes are severe enough to cause disruption of vocational or educational activity then I should be disqualified. In the very beginning that was the case, but now school helps me not to think about it.

The FAA says if I am on medication or have suicidal ideation then I should be disqualified. Well, considering I am getting off my medication in a few weeks that means it's not a required medication, right? And I have never had any suicidal thoughts.

Comment: Mental health questions are tough to answer because there are so many variables and the human mind is a tricky thing. You will need to talk to an aviation medical examiner for this one to get a definitive answer.

Comment: Just to clarify the point about speaking to an AME: ask them for a consultation only, do not apply for an actual medical. If the AME starts a formal medical, it can only end in pass or fail (or deferral to the FAA) and if you fail that can make a lot of things a lot more difficult. So make sure you get everything worked out before you apply.

Comment: I think you are required to have OCD to be a pilot.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe. It depends on how severe the OCD was, the root causes of the disorder, the length of time since the last episode and the likelihood of future recurrence. The aviation medical system is set up to be conservative for good reasons, the cockpit is a bad place to become fixated.

If your condition is/was stress related then I would expect it to be a no, flying can be very stressful at times, you have to be able to handle fluid, difficult scenarios.

Your best answer will be from an Aviation Medical Examiner, I suggest you speak to one, it's what they're for.